# How do you change the encoding of a file, using Perl?

Tags: perl, encoding, ucs2

I'm writing a perl script that creates an xml file "settings.xml". (Using XML::Writer). I'd like the file to be encoded in UCS-2 big endian, but I'm unsure of how.

I've tried things like: `open(my $output, "> :encoding(UCS-2BE)", "settings.xml");`, but all that does is make the file output a big mess,(e.g. either https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfTPk.png or a series of chinese characters) while keeping the encoding of the file as ANSI.

Any idea how to fix this, or alternatively, how to convert a file into UCS-2?

I'm a beginner at Perl, sorry if some of this doesn't make sense.

EDIT: for anyone else encountering this problem, please see the answers below, they provide a thorough explanation of how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try to force encode the content before writing to file ? http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Unicode.html

Comment: Converting from ASCII to UCS-2 just involves widening each 7-bit value to a 16-bit one. What changes did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML::Writer doesn't support anything but US-ASCII and UTF-8 (as mentioned in the documentation of its `ENCODING` constructor argument). Creating an UCS-2be XML document using XML::Writer is tricky, but not impossible.

```
use XML::Writer qw( );

# XML::Writer doesn't encode for you, so we need to use :encoding.
# The :raw avoids a problem with CRLF conversion on Windows.
open(my $fh, '>:raw:encoding(UCS-2be)', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

# This prints the BOM. It's optional, but it's useful when using an
# encoding that's not a superset of US-ASCII (such as UCS-2be).
print($fh "\x{FEFF}");

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(
   OUTPUT   => $fh,
   ENCODING => 'US-ASCII',   # Use entities for > U+007F
);
$writer->xmlDecl('UCS-2be');
$writer->startTag('root');
$writer->characters("\x{00041}");
$writer->characters("\x{000C9}");
$writer->characters("\x{10000}");
$writer->endTag();
$writer->end();
```

Downside: All characters above U+007F will be present as XML entities. In the above example,

- U+00041 will be present as "`A`" (`00 41`). Good.
- U+000C9 will be present as "`&#xC9;`" (`00 26 00 23 00 78 00 43 00 39 00 3B`). Suboptimal, but ok.
- U+10000 will be present as "`&#x10000;`" (`00 26 00 23 00 78 00 31 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 3B`). Good, XML entities are needed to store U+10000 with `UCB-2e`.

---

You can avoid the downside mentioned above if and only if you can guarantee that no character above U+FFFF will be provided to the writer.

```
use XML::Writer qw( );

# XML::Writer doesn't encode for you, so we need to use :encoding.
# The :raw avoids a problem with CRLF conversion on Windows.
open(my $fh, '>:raw:encoding(UCS-2be)', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

# This prints the BOM. It's optional, but it's useful when using an
# encoding that's not a superset of US-ASCII (such as UCS-2be).
print($fh "\x{FEFF}");

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(
   OUTPUT   => $fh,
   ENCODING => 'UTF-8',   # Don't use entities.
);
$writer->xmlDecl('UCS-2be');
$writer->startTag('root');
$writer->characters("\x{00041}");
$writer->characters("\x{000C9}");
#$writer->characters("\x{10000}");  # This causes a fatal error
$writer->endTag();
$writer->end();
```

- U+00041 will be present as "`A`" (`00 41`). Good.
- U+000C9 will be present as "`É`" (`00 C9`). Good.
- U+10000 causes a fatal error.

---

And here's how you can do it without any of the downsides:

```
use Encode      qw( decode encode );
use XML::Writer qw( );

my $xml;
{
   # XML::Writer doesn't encode for you, so we need to use :encoding.
   open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', \$xml);

   # This prints the BOM. It's optional, but it's useful when using an
   # encoding that's not a superset of US-ASCII (such as UCS-2be).
   print($fh "\x{FEFF}");

   my $writer = XML::Writer->new(
      OUTPUT   => $fh,
      ENCODING => 'UTF-8',   # Don't use entities.
   );
   $writer->xmlDecl('UCS-2be');
   $writer->startTag('root');
   $writer->characters("\x{00041}");
   $writer->characters("\x{000C9}");
   $writer->characters("\x{10000}");
   $writer->endTag();
   $writer->end();
   close($fh);
}

# Fix encoding.
$xml = decode('UTF-8', $xml);
$xml =~ s/([^\x{0000}-\x{FFFF}])/ sprintf('&#x%X;', ord($1)) /eg;
$xml = encode('UCS-2be', $xml);

open(my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

print($fh $xml);
```

- U+00041 will be present as "`A`" (`00 41`). Good.
- U+000C9 will be present as "`É`" (`00 C9`). Good.
- U+10000 will be present as "`&#x10000;`" (`00 26 00 23 00 78 00 31 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 3B`). Good, XML entities are needed to store U+10000 with `UCB-2e`.

Comment: Oops, fixed bug in second snippet.

Comment: Added a version with none of the downsides.

Comment: Wow! This worked perfectly, thank you! Since I can guarantee there is no character above UTF-FFFF, I used your second option and it worked perfectly. It seemed that what I was missing was the Byte-order mark and the `:raw` part of `open(my $fh, '>:raw:encoding(UCS-2be)', $qfn)`.

That being said, I also took the time to review the rest of what you wrote, and research a bit more into encoding to supplement what I didn't understand. So thanks for helping a beginner understand a bit more!

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe what goes wrong, but you may be running into a bug some perl versions had on Windows with bad interaction between the encoding and crlf layers.  If so, this should work:

```
open(my $output, "> :raw:perlio:encoding(UCS-2BE):crlf:utf8", "settings.xml");
```

(See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=608532 for an explanation.)

If not, please provide more information than "all that does is make the file output a big mess".  A short script demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies. What happens is one of two things, either I get a long string of japanese (or chinese) characters, or every character in the file is replaced by a black bar with "NULL" inside of it. Using your solution, the included screenshot is my result. (I realize though, the lack of information I provided really didn't help you narrow down what my problem was. http://i.imgur.com/p9cruCf.png

However, using the other answer here, I managed to fix the problem, but thank you for taking the time to respond.